# creating a Sin formula in the c programming language

Tags: c, visual-c++, trigonometry

Hello  everyone I'm trying to implement a programm like the fomular sin
The program will compile but when running it i am not getting the correct values back from my inputs. I'm still getting a negativ value.
can someone help me please ? I had a look at the other posts but that didn't help me :(.
my code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int fac (int a) { // fac. => factorial and i is for the loop

    int i,fac;
        fac=1;

    for (i=1; i<=a; i++){
        fac=fac*i;
    }
    return fac;
}
int power_func(int x,int y) // x is exponent and y is the number that would be multiplied by itself.
     {
         int i;//i is for the loop
         int ret = 1;
         for(i=1;i<=x;i++)
         {
             ret *= y;
         }
         return ret;
     }
int main()
{
    int num,denom,i;//num. is numerator and denom. is denominator
    int sin,x,result=0;
    printf("Enter the number of x \n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {

    num= power_func(2*i+1,x);
    denom=fac((2*i+1));
    sin=power_func(i,-1)*num/denom;
    result =result+sin;
    printf("%d \n",result);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `power_func` is not correct. It computes `y^(2^x)`.

Comment: @lurker I have changed this line to num= power_func(x, 2*i+1); but I still get a wong answer like     :                          Enter the number of x
3(
,-1.000000
,1092.000000
,4347.000000) the result

Comment: See my initial comment about it being incorrectly calculated. Sorry, I was mistaken about the backward part.

Comment: ohh mmm  it's ok @lurker

Comment: More specifically, `y = y*y` is a problem...

Comment: Also `power_func` expects integers. You're passing a float. And `sin=power_func(i,-1)*num/denom;` is integer arithmetic.

Comment: The condition `i < x` is dubious. And you don't need factorials and power functions to expand the series. You can calculate the next term from the current one: −x³ / 3! = −x² / (3·2)·x; x⁵ / 5! = −x² / (5·4) · −x³/3! and so on. This will also prevent numerical problems: Integer factorials can only go up to 12!

Comment: sin( x)= ∑ =(−1) x^ 2k+1/(2k+ 1)! for x∈R I used them because I have to follow this formula

Comment: Yes, that's the formula.  @MOehm suggested method *does* follow the formula! It's just a more efficient way to compute it. Looking at it more simply, if you need to compute 1!, then 3!, then 5!, and so on, when computing 5! you don't have to compute 1*2*3*4*5 since you already did 1*2*3 when you computed 3! You just need to take 3!*4*5 to get 5!.

Comment: I know what you mean but for me it's the same if I wirte so 1*2*3*4*5 or 3!*4*5 I will get the same result

Comment: You get the same result but a precomputed 3! times 4*5 is a lot less CPU intensive than recomputing 1*2*3 in the process!

Comment: It is not only about the efficiency of your algorithm. Implementing the formula verbatim leads to precision loss. How many terms do you want to calculate? (Your code says `i < x`, but that's definitely wrong.) The 7th term has 13!, but that cannot be represented by an `int`. The formula is a nice, compact representation for mathematicians, but it is not suitable for computation. In particular, (−1)ⁿ is just a fancy way to say "alternating sign". ([This article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130508-00/?p=4423/) may be relevant.)

Comment: mm I know that the datatype(int) should be something else but I don't which one should I choose float , long double.  And (How many terms do you want to calculate?) I denpendes on my inputs (I think ) If I input 5 the should be 5 terms.

Comment: Most of your variables should have floating-point type. That's the principal error here. The (mathematical) function sin(x) takes any real argument and returns a real between −1 and 1. You can't represent that with integers. How many terms you want to use depends on how accurate your term should be. The closer x is to zero, the fewer terms you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have various misconceptions about your code. First, let's look at the formula you have provided:

```
sin(x) = sum((−1)^k * x^(2*k + 1) / (2*k + 1)!   for x ∈ R;   k = 0, ..., infinity
```

The sine function takes a real and returns a real. Therefore, you should use a floating-point type for x and sin(x). Use a `double`. Let's also write a function that emulates `sin` from `<math.h>`:

```
double my_sin(double x);
```

The above series is accurate when there are infinitely many terms. We can't calculate that many, of course, and it would be a waste of time, too, because the terms are getting ever smaller until they can no longer be represented by a `double`. So let's chose a maximum number of terms, say

```
enum {
    nTerms = 8
};
```

Factorials grow big fast. A regular 32-bit int can hold 12! = 479,001,600. A 64-bit int can hold 20! = 2,432,902,008,176,640,000. Since we are going to use these factorials in a `double` calculation, we can just as well use `double` here. That will even allow us to represent 22! = 1,124,000,727,777,607,680,000 accurately.

Your power function should also have a `double` base. The exponent is integer. (But please use the more natural order `power(base, exp)`.

Finally, `(−1)^k` is just an alternating sign. It is positive when `k` is even and odd otherwise.

Putting all this together:

```
double fact(int n)
{
    double result = 1.0;

    while (n > 0) {
        result *= n;
        n--;
    }

    return result;
}

double power(double a, int n)
{
    double result = 1.0;

    while (n > 0) {
        result *= a;
        n--;
    }

    return result;
}

enum {
    nTerms = 8
};

double my_sin(double x)
{
    double result = 0.0;
    double sign = 1.0;

    for(int k = 0; k < nTerms; k++)
    {
        double num = power(x, 2*k + 1);
        double denom = fact(2*k + 1);
        double term = sign * num / denom;

        result = result + term;
        sign = -sign;
    }

    return result;
}
```

If we write a driver program to print out some test values and compare them with the standard math library's implementation of `sin`:

```
int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        double x = 0.1 * i;
        double m = my_sin(x);       // series approximation
        double s = sin(x);          // <math.h> implementation

        printf("%16g%16g%16g%16g\n", x, m, s, m - s);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

we can see that we're not doing so badly:

```
           x       my_sin(x)          sin(x)      difference
    --------    ------------    ------------    ------------
           0               0               0               0
         0.1       0.0998334       0.0998334     1.38778e-17
         0.2        0.198669        0.198669     2.77556e-17
         0.3         0.29552         0.29552               0
         0.4        0.389418        0.389418    -5.55112e-17
         0.5        0.479426        0.479426               0
         0.6        0.564642        0.564642               0
         0.7        0.644218        0.644218               0
         0.8        0.717356        0.717356               0
         0.9        0.783327        0.783327    -4.44089e-16
           1        0.841471        0.841471    -2.77556e-15
         1.1        0.891207        0.891207    -1.43219e-14
         1.2        0.932039        0.932039    -6.20615e-14
         1.3        0.963558        0.963558    -2.42029e-13
         1.4         0.98545         0.98545    -8.52318e-13
```

(But it gets worse the farther we go from zero. Try other values for `nTerms`.)

---

I've said in a comment above that you don't need to calculate factorials and powers and that's true. If you look at the terms of the series, you will see that:

```
s[n] = -1 * s[n - 1] * x^2 / (2*n * (2*n +1))

s[0] = x
s[1] = x^3 / (1 * 2 * 3)         =                 x * x^2 / (2 * 3)
s[2] = x^5 / (1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5) = x^3 / (1 * 2 * 3) * x^2 / (4 * 5)
s[3] = ...
```

Here's a function that implements that.It calculates terms until adding them to the sum doesn't change it, because they are too small:

```
double sin_r(double x)
{
    double sum = x;
    double a = x;
    int n;

    for (n = 1; ; n++) {
        double was = sum;

        a = -a * x*x / (2*n) / (2*n + 1);
        sum += a;

        if (was == sum) break;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

The addition still loses some precision by summing the first terms first, but it has the benefit that it doesn't have to calculate factorials and powers. You don't even need `<math.h>`.